# Google AdMob, не показывается тестовая реклама

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads

Изучаю использование AdMob, создалл ак на AdMob, подключил FireBase, AdMob, добавил вьюшку, но тестовою рекламу я так и не увидел. Возможно я не туда повставлял Id:

```
fun initAds() {
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-8xxxxxxxxxxxxxx0~7yyyyyyyyy6")
//  { Log.e("AdsMobFucks", "${it.adapterStatusMap.values}")}

    val request = AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("7ddddddddddddddddd1")
        .build()

    adsBanner.loadAd(request)
}

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adsBanner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8xxxxxxxxxxxxxx0/6yyyyyyyy2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-8xxxxxxxxxxxxxx0~7yyyyyyyy6"/>
```

Гуглил, думал может она вовсе не показывается, но обычно тестовая есть, а обычной нету.

**UPD:** Возможно есть какой-то другой способ проверить работоспособность.

Comment: Согласно документации, эмуляторы уже настроены на показ тестовой рекламы, так что не нужно что-то добавлять. Полная документация: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: @Style-7, ну это как-то не особо помагает, из-за этого и были добавлены эти параметры.

Comment: так вы полностью изменили вопрос, то вам тестовая, то вам обычная уже

Comment: @Style-7, Только добавил одну строчку. Я думаю что если мы говорим о тестовой рекламе, значит мы подразумеваем цель проверить работоспособность данной функции (сервиса). Раз её нет, значит по логике и нормальная работать не будет.

Comment: уже не понятно на реальном устройстве или эмуляторе вы хотите увидеть НЕ тестовую рекламу. На эмуляторе судя по документации этого сделать не удастся (только тест). По моему опыту в debug версии тоже. Реально нужно сделать/подписать release версию.

Comment: @Style-7, на AVD я никогда и не пытался увидеть реальную рекламу, паруменут гуглинга и это будет понятно что это не получится, да и смысла не имеет. Увидеть тестовую рекламу нужно только для того что бы понять: правильноли подключена библиотека и как оно будет смотреться на экране. Если вы её используете ещё для каких-то целей, это круто, но как по мне, тестовая реклама никакой практической пользы, больше не несёт.

Comment: поверьте, что в Google люди по умнее сидят чем вы или я. Тестовая реклама нужна - это гарант, что покажется обычная, и что самое главное не несет коммерческого ущерба рекламодателю (а по сути воровства)

Comment: @Style-7, мне просто интересно, а чем то что вы написали, отличается от поста выше?